# IBM Worklight 7.1 : Authorization error while invoking an secured Worklight adapter procedure from hybrid application

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to execute the sample application given [here](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/authentication-security/adapter-based-authentication/adapter-based-authentication-hybrid-applications/) but facing issues. When I click on the "Get Secret" data button, the request reaches the adapter but I get a failed response as below.

```
04-29 22:12:22.464: I/chromium(2802): [INFO:CONSOLE(34)] "=======getSecretData_CallbackFail========={"responseHeaders":{"X-Powered-By":"Servlet/3.0","Content-Type":"text/plain; charset=UTF-8","Content-Length":"21","Date":"Sat, 29 Apr 2017 16:41:31 GMT","WWW-Authenticate":"Bearer realm=\"imfAuthentication\", scope=\"AuthRealm\""},"status":401,"responseText":"missing_authorization","errorMsg":"Unauthorized","invocationContext":null}", source: file:///android_asset/www/default/js/main.js (34)
```

I am testing the application from an Android phone. Can someone suggest what am I doing wrong?

```
function getSecretData(){
    var resourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest("/adapters/AuthenticationService/getSecretData", WLResourceRequest.GET, 30000);
    resourceRequest.send().then(
        getSecretData_CallbackOK,
        getSecretData_CallbackFail
    );
}
```

The above code is used at client to invoke the adapter. The `onAuthRequired` function is called but `errormessage` is undefined.

```
function onAuthRequired(headers, errorMessage){
    WL.Logger.info("Authservice onAuthRequired--->"+errorMessage);
    errorMessage = errorMessage ? errorMessage : null;
    return {
        authRequired: true,
        errorMessage: errorMessage
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your adapter's secret data is protected with realm `AuthRealm` and whenever client makes request to protected adapter endpoint, it throws 401 unauthorized error. Basically 401 is a challenge thrown by server.

Check whether you have declared registered challenge handler with `AuthRealm` realm in client code as explained in [this](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/authentication-security/adapter-based-authentication/adapter-based-authentication-hybrid-applications/) tutorial. Once client answers server challenge successfully with the help of challenge handler, server will return the secret data.

Comment: There was an error in my adapter onAuthRequired(). Client was expecting authstatus, but adapter is returing authRequired. After correcting this, it worked. But still have an issue. I don't see the getSecretData() is called. onAuthRequired() is called without calling getSecretData(). The log statement in the getSecretData() is not present in the worklight log. Any clue on this.. below is the code                    function getSecretData(){
 WL.Logger.info("Authservice getSecretData--->");
    return {
        secretData: "Very very very very secret data"
    };
}

Comment: What do you get as a response to the adapter call?